# Colcon build failed to build nav2_util

Tags: ros, navigation, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04 ROS Foxy.

Following the instruction on navigation tutorial (https://navigation.ros.org/build_instructions/index.html) to build navigation stack. I downloaded the files from the repo git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2.git --branch foxy-devel

After running colcon build command, the building process failed while trying to build nav2_util with the following error message:

```
--- stderr: nav2_util                                
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/fibonacci.hpp:9,
                 from /home/paulolui/navigation2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_util/test/test_actions.cpp:22:
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:23:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
   23 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_Goal>()
      |                         ^
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:52:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
   52 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_Result>()
      |                         ^
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:81:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
   81 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_Feedback>()
      |                         ^
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/fibonacci.hpp:9,
                 from /home/paulolui/navigation2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_util/test/test_actions.cpp:22:
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:116:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  116 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_SendGoal_Request>()
      |                         ^
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/fibonacci.hpp:9,
                 from /home/paulolui/navigation2_ws/src/navigation2/nav2_util/test/test_actions.cpp:22:
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:149:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  149 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_SendGoal_Response>()
      |                         ^
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:178:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  178 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_SendGoal>()
      |                         ^
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:238:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  238 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_GetResult_Request>()
      |                         ^
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:272:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  272 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_GetResult_Response>()
      |                         ^
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:301:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  301 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_GetResult>()
      |                         ^
/opt/ros/foxy/include/test_msgs/action/detail/fibonacci__traits.hpp:364:25: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
  364 | inline const char * name<test_msgs::action::Fibonacci_FeedbackMessage>()
      |                         ^
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/test_actions.dir/build.make:63: test/CMakeFiles/test_actions.dir/test_actions.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:443: test/CMakeFiles/test_actions.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< nav2_util [38.2s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 6 packages finished [44.3s]
  1 package failed: nav2_util
  1 package had stderr output: nav2_util
  22 packages not processed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361814/colcon-build-failed-to-build-nav2_util/) by [PLui](https://answers.ros.org/users/59240/plui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrunaljsarvaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/58908/mrunaljsarvaiya/) on 2020-10-12**:
I'm having the same issue, did you figure this out?

**Comment by [chiyaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56720/chiyaan/) on 2022-09-16**:
I have this issue in rolling distro..Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This build failure is in the tests, which aren't critical to building the `nav2_util` package.  Comment out the [three lines](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/foxy-devel/nav2_util/test/CMakeLists.txt#L20-L22) configuring the broken `test_actions.cpp` test in `nav2_util/test/CMakeLists.txt` and try again.  (I actually haven't tried this repo, but fixed a [similar issue](https://github.com/ros-controls/realtime_tools/issues/65) in the `ros-controls/realtime_tools` repo; it's possible this isn't the only issue.)

This problem actually originates in a maze of little problems; here's a summary and links to the gory details:

- The compiler error is a result of the `fibonacci` action headers in the `ros-foxy-test-msgs` Debian package being [generated by a newer version](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl/issues/544) of the `rosidl_runtime_cpp` ROS package (v. `1.1.0`+) than the actual `ros-foxy-rosidl-runtime-cpp` package currently shipped in Foxy (v. `1.0.1`)
- [It's a miracle](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/issues/114) the `fibonacci` action even exists in the `ros-foxy-test-msgs` v. `1.0.0` package, given that the now-obsolete action was removed from the `test_msgs` source in git tag `0.7.2`
- Now there are issues in the [`ros-planning/navigation2` repo](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/2069) and [`ros-controls/realtime_tools` repo](https://github.com/ros-controls/realtime_tools/issues/65) noting that the obsolete action needs to be removed in ROS2 branches to avoid build failures

---

Originally posted by [zultron](https://answers.ros.org/users/34470/zultron/) with karma: 51 on 2020-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2